# Fluent NHibernate with NHibernate 3.0

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

With NHibernate 3 going GA today, I was wondering if I can upgrade a project that is using Fluent NHibernate. Can i simply swap out the 2.1 DLL for the 3.0 and have it work? - Or is there more to it than that?

I know there will be some work with the change in Linq syntax but i am not concerned with that, I just want to know if the DLLs are interchangeable for Fluent.

Many thanks,

Kohan

---

## Addendum

The Fluent guys have done it themselves now:
http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

drlongnecker has built Fluent NHibernate for NHibernate 3.0GA. You can grab the source [**here**](https://github.com/drlongnecker/fluent-nhibernate).

**Update:** [**Fluent Nhibernate**](http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads) now officially builds pre-release binaries with NHibernate 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build them together. Can wait for NuGet to be updated or you can build them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can put assembly redirect