# Fluent NHibernate and NHibernate version issue

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.2.0.2002, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: You'll need to provide far more information than that if you want a useful answer!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fluent NHibernate with NHibernate 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365395/fluent-nhibernate-with-nhibernate-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a number of things, but the most probable cause is that your start up project does not reference the assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.2.0.2002, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' although other assemblies you have referenced use the assembly.

Add the assembly to the start up project and you shall be fine.

And please try to ask questions in a better manner.

Comment: Sorry, but i was so much pissed off, i just posted incomplete question ... let me try this and i will get back to on this ... thanks anyways

Comment: its not working for me ... can it be cause my VS2010 is not installed in the same c:\ but other

Answer (score 0):

It seems FHN has not a build for NH 3.2 yet, because it's in RC state right now.
So you can use [asm binding redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) for now.